# A word for a group of people in a church

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there a *a single specific  word*  for a the group of people when they assist at Mass in a church?

*Religious assembly*  ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=religious%20assembly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creligious%20assembly%3B%2Cc0)) is a common expression whose usage appears to have been decreasing in the last decades.

The term I am looking for may fit also to other religious contexts as long as it refers to people who gather for an official religious rite.

Synonyms like: convocation, ingathering, meeting, etc. do not sound appropriate.

Comment: A suggestion to clarify the question...  The people who _assist_ a rite are not (necessarily) the same as the people who _gather for_ the rite.  For example, in a Christian context, few of those who gather for Eucharist would be said to be assisting in it.  Which are you looking for?

Comment: I'd use *congregation*. In some Protestant denominations that's also used loosely for all the members of a particular church, but that's really just an extension of the meaning.

Comment: @Morton Until quite recently (basically VII) all those who participate in a Roman Catholic mass were said to "assist at" it. I don't know whether that's derived from the old sense of "attend" (still the fundamental meaning of French *assister*) or has some deeper spiritual significance.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you - I should have said "Christian protestant", since that's all I really know about. In that sense, +1 for _congregation_... but I'll duck out here since the question was about Mass in particular.

Comment: At Holy Communion in the Anglican Church (equivalent to the Roman Catholic *Mass*), those participating are said to be *communicants*. I am not sure, however, if that applies to those participating on a particular occasion or those who do so regularly.

Comment: *churchgoers* ?

Comment: @ermanen - that refers to a person who goes to church, especially  regularly, rather than to the assembly of people who assist at  Mass.

Comment: @Josh61: Well, I kind of answered the question in the title. Also, "churchgoer" is specifically related to church and nothing else.

Comment: Look up synonyms of 'congregation'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word I would use is **congregation**:

> Full Definition of CONGREGATION 1 a :  an assembly of persons : 
>   gathering; especially :  an assembly of persons met for worship and
>   religious instruction. - *[Merriam Webster](http://Full%20Definition%20of%20CONGREGATION%201%20a%20:%20%20an%20assembly%20of%20persons%20:%20%20gathering;%20especially%20:%20%20an%20assembly%20of%20persons%20met%20for%20worship%20and%20religious%20instruction)*

Comment: That is an interesting term , to me it is mainly associated with  a group of people regularly attending a particular place of worship, 
like  *a member of the Emmanuel Chapel congregation*.

Comment: @Josh61 The congregation is the group of people in the church, rather like *audience* is the group of people in a theatre.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - yes, I see that is one of its main meanings , it is just me probably that have always associated it with *specific congregations.*

Comment: @Josh61 As per SamuelVimes answer, that would be the *parish*.

Answer (score 2):

A more poetic answer would be "flock." Which is used metaphorically in Christianity when to Jesus is referred to as the Good Shepard. Otherwise congregation is the best, more descriptive and commonly used word.

Answer (score 1):

[This reference from the US Conference of Catholic Bishops](http://www.usccb.org/about/media-relations/upload/how-to-cover-the-mass.pdf) seems to use *ministers* as a term that would include ordained *celebrants* and *lay participants* assisting in the mass.  But they're pretty adamant the only *celebrants* are ordained.

In a religious gathering, conclave--whatever you want to call it-- where the participants are peers, though, I think you could call everyone ***celebrants***, though perhaps that is because I am [North American](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/celebrant).

All that said, I think the other answer of congregation/congregants is more appropriate, especially if everyone attending is to be included.

Comment: I would avoid *celebrant* as freighted. In Catholic, Orthodox, and Anglican traditions it indeed refers solely to the priest saying the Mass, and not to any other participants. When applied to any other participants, therefore, some may infer a theological position of the *priesthood of the faithful* as opposed to the ordained priesthood.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ***parish*** or ***parishioners***. Otherwise, I think that Margana's ***congregation*** is another good choice.

According to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/):

***[parish](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parish?showCookiePolicy=true)***

> noun
>
> 1) a subdivision of a diocese, having its own church and a clergyman related adjective parochial
>   2) the churchgoers of such a subdivision

Comment: IME, members of the parish are those who regularly attend that specific church. The congregation are those who are present today, regardless of their affiliation. E.g., *Today's congregation welcomes members from the parish of X, as X had a roof leak.*

Comment: A *parishioner, as Collins says, is somone who lives in the parish. They may not go to church at all, much less for a specific Mass.

Answer (score 0):

[Communicants](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/communicant),  as mentioned in comments, is the word specifically for those who take communion in any Christian denomination. It is sometimes necessary to distinguish those who partake from the remainder of the congregation; if so the record may show "Attendance 100: communicants 80". (The stationery for this, called *church service registers*, is largely interdenominational, implying but not proving that Roman Catholics also use the word.) I do not believe there is a word (other than *non-communicants*) for the other 20.